# How does a "hammer thrower" that we see in the Olympics, impart so much momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, everyday-life

How does a "hammer thrower" that we see in the Olympics, build so much momentum into the club?

It's sort of like the golf swing, the more momentum, primarily in the club head, the further the ball will fly, not accounting for the "Magnus effect".

So, how does a strong hammer thrower, create so much power?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood the question.
My interpretation is just this.

Consider the hammer, still secured to the hand of the athlete through the chain or rope or whatever. While it rotates, it has an angular frequency $\omega$. This implies its linear speed is $\omega r$, where $r$ is the length of the rope. When the hammer is released, with no more constraints, it will go straight on in the direction it has, with the same speed $\omega r$.

Now, to increase this, obviously, you can increase $\omega$ or $r$. The radius is fixed by the rules of the sport in 121.5 cm.

$\omega$ is transmitted to the hammer by the athlete. If you watch a video, you can notice the first couple of turns is given by rotating the arm, then the athlete himself rotates, and impresses an angular acceleration by moving their feet accordingly. Exactly as a runner, but rotating instead of running straight on.

I don't know if this was the point, perhaps this answer sounds trivial...

Comment: The hulking strength of a hammer thrower is then important to create sufficiently large centripetal forces, which goes with the angular velocity squared.

Comment: Interesting, moving ones feet around rather than in a straight line is, I take it, how force is derived from the earth, conveyed into the hammer, and then released at a ninety degree angle from the target; it's kind of like golf.

Comment: I wouldn't say "derived from the earth" but I guess you understood the idea. If you're satisfied, please accept the answer.